# How can you use javascript and JQuery together to make an IF Else statement for a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the original code you would click a checkbox that would enable a button that was disabled.

This is using Bootstrap 3.  I was having problems with 2 JQuery elements (a slider with many js elements) getting in the way of a code that worked well on it's own, here is the example:

http://www.bootply.com/AlUZOz0zXB

Because of these Java scripts being used for a sliding carousel:

```
<script src="js/flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

It gets in the way of the JQuery for some reason.  So I wanted to design the code to work possible with pure javascript:

http://www.bootply.com/SToIs8u2gM

Comment: Can you define "gets in the way"? Are there errors? What is breaking?

Comment: They don't produce any visible errors, it just doesn't enable the button

Comment: What button? You need to show your code, explain what it's supposed to do, and what's wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve], and include the code in the question itself... Looking at the code in the "bootply", you are not attaching your `check()` function to anything.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass some sort of a value to the button to indicate wheather it needs to be enabled or not. You can do that by leveraging ng-model attribute on the checkbox, and bounding it's value to the disabled attribute on the button. 
Do this, and it will work

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="checkbox"> 
            <label>
              <input class="check_list" name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
              I accept the Terms
            </label>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" disabled={{checkboxModel.value1}}>Accept Terms</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And what do I do for the javascript?  I tend to know more on JQuery Javascript than regular Java Script

Comment: this alone will make the "accept terms" button clickable, when you check the checkbox. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I have a bootply trying this, but not sure how to use it in the javascript :   http://www.bootply.com/YlC6YOpvBc#

Comment: you don't need your check function anymore. Angular takes care of enabling/disabling the button based on wheather the checkbox is checked. http://www.bootply.com/IbvMWHSJ4m#

Comment: It tried it and it wouldn't go, that's why I wondered if there was something I was missing. I updated it with the above code:  http://www.bootply.com/7HwMNRKM0g

Answer (score 0):

http://tutorialsplane.com/runtest/try.php?trycode=bootstrap-disable-enable-button-jquery&post_code=code7&

I basically did this that worked.  I thought it would conflict but it didn't:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){
$("#myBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
$('#myBtn').removeClass('disabled');
$("#myBtn1").attr("disabled", true);
$('#myBtn1').addClass('disabled');
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="checkbox"> 
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-danger " onclick="enable()" id="myBtn1" value="Enable Button" />
          I accept the Terms
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger disaabled" disabled id="myBtn" value="Disabled Button" />
    <br>
  </div>
```